# How to fix this error in hadoop hive vanilla

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

**I am facing the following error while executing MapReduce job in Linux(CentOS). I added all the jars in classpath. The database name and table name already in the hive database with some column of data in the table. Then also I can't able to access the data from the hive database table.
I'm using vanilla version of hadoop for work. Should i need to edit hive-site.xml file by mysql driver path, username and password for hive?. if yes please tell me the procedure to add username and password for hive. Thank you in advance**

```html
murali]# hadoop jar /home/murali/workspace/hadoop/HiveInputForMapper/target/HiveInputForMapper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver -libjars $LIBJARS
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library /hadoop/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
14/11/21 11:26:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/11/21 11:26:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
14/11/21 11:26:20 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
14/11/21 11:26:20 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
14/11/21 11:26:20 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
14/11/21 11:26:22 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
14/11/21 11:26:22 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: MySQL check failed, assuming we are not on mysql: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO DataNucleus.Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
14/11/21 11:26:23 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_databases: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_databases: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=bigdata tbl=categories
14/11/21 11:26:24 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=root ip=unknown-ip-addr cmd=get_table : db=bigdata tbl=categories 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: NoSuchObjectException(message:bigdata.categories table not found)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:97)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:71)
 at com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver.run(HiveInputDriver.java:27)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
 at com.cosmonet.HiveInputDriver.main(HiveInputDriver.java:49)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:bigdata.categories table not found)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_table(HiveMetaStore.java:1560)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:105)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.get_table(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:997)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTable(HCatUtil.java:191)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:105)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
 at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
 ... 10 more
```

Comment: What happens when you fire the query like USE bigdata
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'categories'?

Comment: should i parse whole command at once..??if i split it 2 commands then it will work correctly

Comment: I too have a similar problem. Added hive-site.xml through -conf option while running the MR. Still the issue persists. Can someone help?